# How to get AppID based on valid AccessToken and/or Facebook.FacebookClient object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm logged in using to my own Application using [C# Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) and I can read/write/delete all data I need.

However for validation purposes I'd like to get AppID that I'm currently using (the one I used when generating login Uri) based on existing valid Access-token and Facebook.FacebookClient object.

In a similar way like in Facebook PHP SDK: [`$appId = Facebook->getAppId();`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAppId/)

My access token is not like `string.Concat(appId, "|", appSecret)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use [Facebook C# Sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) I may use following code to retrieve appID I used when loging in - if at the moment I have in memmory only AccessToken available:

```
string myAccessToken = "...";
FacebookClient fc = new FacebookClient(myAccessToken);
IDictionary<string, object> resultContainer = 
          (IDictionary<string, object>)fc.Get("/app");
string retrievedAppID = resultContainer["id"] as string;
```

The same result can be obtained directly from [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/app
```

If desired Facebook application is selected at top right part of the Graph Api Explorer page.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Facebook C# SDK`, there is no where that `access_token` parses(or decoded).

Naturally, `Facebook C# SDK` api, it takes `appId` from `Web.Config`  through the `FacebookSettings` class.
`access_token` as string property of FacebookSignedRequest class.

So you may follow this link to do it yourself: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I found different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the `AppId` like this:

```
var appId = Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this works only if I initialize the FacebookApplication.Current in the AppDomain (evt. Process) that does the login as well. Else -> as I described I can use the Access-token but have not FacebookApplication.Current instance available.